# Subdocument schemas not working

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to build a Mongoose Schema that includes a subdocument, so I can have a single document with user info and their contacts. The idea is to be able to have CRUD capabilities on the Contacts subdocument without requiring a separate collection.

(Sorry for stating the obvious, just want to be clear)

So parent schema is "User" and sub it "Contacts"...

I coded up my model like this:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    login: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    firstname:{
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    contacts:[ContactSchema]
})


var  ContactSchema = new Schema({
    contactFirstName:{ 
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    contactLastName:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    contactEmail: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

But when I run my API, I get an error stating:

**TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `contacts`**

I'm fairly new to Mongoose, but from what I've seen, this is how you implement a subdocument.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Here is a sample route I want to call in my Express API:

```
router.route('/')

//CREATE NEW USER
.post(function(req, res){

  var user = new User();
  user.login = req.body.login;
  user.firstname = req.body.firstname;
  user.lastname = req.body.lastname;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.password = req.body.password;

  user.contacts.contactFirstName = req.body.contacts.contactFirstName;
  user.contacts.contactLastName = req.body.contacts.contactLastName;

  user.save(function(err){
    if(err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({message:'User has been created'});
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of Mongoose I dont think the [someSchema] is necessary. You can just put someSchema. So no array brackets. If you are working with an older version try utilizing the .add with the schema. So something like this.

`var ContactSchema = new Schema();
 ContactSchema.add({
   contactFirstName:{ 
        type    : String,
        required: true
    },
    contactLastName:{
        type    : String,
        required: true
    },
    contactEmail: {
        type    : String,
        required: true
    }
})`

Than add your `contacts:[ContactSchema]` to the UserSchema

Comment: Thanks @mrtaz. I tried just removing the brackets and calling the var directly after (contacts:contactSchema) and got the same error. I'm using mongoose 4.5.5.

Comment: Add the contact schema above user

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path, just a simple mistake. You have used `ContactSchema` in `UserSchema` without defining it, that's why it is coming as undefined.

Define your `ContactSchema` before defining `UserSchema`,and then use it in contacts array. It should work fine.

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    //rest of the variables...
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    contacts:[ContactSchema]
})


var  ContactSchema = new Schema({
    contactFirstName:{ 
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    //other variables...
});
```

**Update:**

while creating new `user`, you are not defining `user.contacts` as an `object`, you are directly trying to assign value to `user.contacts.contactFirstName`  and `user.contacts.contactLastName`. But, since user.contact is not defined, it is coming as `undefined`, and hence the `error`:  **Cannot read property 'contactFirstName' of undefined** will come.

Add `user.contacts = {};` before assigning value to `user.contacts.contactFirstName`  and `user.contacts.contactLastName`.

```
user.contacts = {};//add this line
user.contacts.contactFirstName = req.body.contacts.contactFirstName;
user.contacts.contactLastName = req.body.contacts.contactLastName;
```

Comment: Thanks Ravi! What's the best way to test this in PostMan?

Comment: Thanks Ravi. I switched them around and I don't get that error when running the API. However, when I try to test in PostMan, I try to add one of the fields using the key "contacts.contactFirstName" and I get an undefined message: ""error": "Cannot read property 'contactFirstName' of undefined""

Comment: What are you trying to do with postman, I mean which route are you testing? Can you post the route code which you are testing.

Comment: Hi Ravi, I added a sample route above.